# How to find `type` of Gradle task?

Tags: gradle

I have the following code which works fine:

```groovy
allprojects {
  tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name =~ /generate.*Proto/) { // ①
      task.dependsOn(protolockStatus)
      task.finalizedBy(protolockCommit)
    }
  }
}
```

Rather than assuming some task naming convention on the line commented with ①, I'd like to make the condition based on the type of the task. I had thought `type instanceof` would work, but it did not. I also don't see any methods that would provide the type of the task. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `class` of the task for that. So for example, you could try this:

```groovy
allprojects {
    tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
        println "Type is " + task.class.simpleName
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose I could do that. But why doesn't `instanceof` work?

Comment: It turns out that `task`'s `Class` exists in a different `ClassLoader`.